# Symfony3.4 custom command

Tags: symfony, command

I'm trying to create a personnal command to change data in my database. I could do it directly with a "SELECT *" ... but Symfony says that the good method is to create a command to apply changes in database, etc... So this is the problem i'm facing :

When I override the default __construct method, the Command is not auto-registered by Symfony, which means Symfony just ignore it. When I delete the constructor, my command works but I just get null from my $entitymanager (which is logic since I put nothing into entitymanager ?).

Does anyone have a solution for me please ? Sorry for my bad english and thank you for your help:)

[So here is my code for the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lDJB.png)

Comment: Don't use images in questions.  Just copy/paste in your constructor code.  I suspect you are not calling the parent constructor.  Follow the example in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here another alternative to use entityManager in your 3.4 since autowiring is not as good as 4.0 and above 
`class CreateUserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager(); 
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Thank u, i've another problem now : i'm catch a fatal error which is " Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager could not
   be converted to string" i'll try to find it on internet

Comment: Okay I just find out the problem I was using this : "$applications = $this->$entityManager->getRepository('Corsaire4Bundle:Application')->findAll();" and the solution was to delete $this

Comment: Please mark it as resolved if you find my answer usefull

Answer (score 0):

Version of Symfony?

However try to this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
[...]

class CreateUserCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:create-user';

    /**
    * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager,
        string $name = null
    ) {
    parent::__construct($name);
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        [...]
    }

        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        [...]
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working, i'm on Symfony 3.4 since the application is old.

Comment: what does the class extend?

Comment: here is my class name and extend : "class ResetPmStatusCommand extends Command" 

So my class is extending Command

Answer (score 0):

You need to autowire the  *EntityManagerInterface* $entityManager not the  EntityManager and make sur that autowiring is enable if not you need to manually do it in your service.yml

Comment: Thx for you answer, my autowiring is set as "true" in app/config/services.yml. I tried EntityManagerInterface but it's still not working. :(

Comment: And are you sure you are not excluding Command in the autowiring ?

Comment: I don't think so, I've nothing in services.yml telling to excluding Command in the autowiring. Is there a method to check that ?

Answer (score -1):

the `parent::__construct` should always be the first line.

Move this line and it's should work fine.

```
{
    parent::__construct();    
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? The order of those two lines will make no difference.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, and of course, it changes something. When parent call is before, you init all the dependencies that you need ( like command registration, etc).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Sadly it's not working, my command is still ignored :(.